# Improve "not interested" message to employers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

Currently when you respond that you're "not interested" to a message from an employer, the following message will appear in the thread:

> {Name}
>
> Is **not interested** in this role.

Is this exactly what employers see?

If so, it kind of seems like I'm the one who actually wrote that message, in broken English, and not particularly politely.

Can we change this to make it clearer that this is a generated message in response to an action I took, not something I wrote?

Perhaps:

> {Name} has indicated that they are **not interested** in this role.

Or even just putting it on the same line could be enough:

> {Name} is **not interested** in this role.

And we should probably change the "interested" message appropriately as well.

Comment: I mean, any employer probably gets MORE of these than positive answers. By now they must have figured out that this is automatically generated (if that's even how they see it)

Comment: @Patrice Probably, but it could still be improved, and likely still affects what the employer ends up thinking of you (how much, I wouldn't know, and yes, I know I can write a message if I care so much, but this could still be improved). Some employers who reach out very selectively, or just those who are new here, may not have seen a whole lot of these messages though.

Comment: @Patrice just because something works now doesn't mean you can't make it better... Besides politeness is the key to success (or one of them anyway). Also any new employer to the SO may think this rude and from the account holder.

Comment: RyanfaeScotland doesn't think speaking in the third person constitutes 'broken English'. RyanfaeScotland thinks it sounds quite dramatic and adds gravitas to what is being said.

Comment: I saw this when replying to a job just yesterday and had the same thought (I wanted to leave a followup message that said why I wasn't interested when I saw it, turned out that I was interested).  Oh, and it actually looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGZzI.png), which is what makes it look like broken English.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I was thinking it looks more like "I am not interested", but with a missing "I" and "am" changed to "is".

Answer (score 19):

I see the response:

> **NotThatGuy replied** not interested **and wrote:**
>
> *No response text*

So it is pretty clear what you wrote (I don't think anyone has ever written "No response text") and what came from stackoverflow.

Also, I wouldn't worry about what an employer that you aren't interested in thinks of you.  And the answer is: nothing much, it is pretty clearly an automated reply from stack overflow from a click of a button that gives the employer exactly what they need to know so we can move on to the next ad.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the benefit of even seeing these? Other than as aggregate stats (40 developers indicated they weren't interested in your position this week), do you literally have to see every individual one?

Comment: @SteveBennett, these are replies to a message from a company saying "hey we thought you might like this position".  It can be good to know that the message has been seen and that they aren't interested, as opposed to no reply which could just be that they haven't got around to looking at the job ad yet.

Comment: Oh, cool - sorry I misunderstood the context. (Didn't read the OP closely enough).

Comment: concerning your 2.ed paragraph: You might worry because chances are, that you are not interested in *this* position but another one from the same employer

Comment: Next time I respond I'm not interested, I'm definitely typing: "No response text".

Comment: Or better yet [This is not the text that your looking for](https://giphy.com/gifs/starwars-movie-star-wars-l2JJKs3I69qfaQleE/fullscreen)

Comment: You can discuss the theory as much as you wish. In practice I do not reply a lot of messages from employers because I have to tell in advance if I'm interested or not. Either I have a question or they lack some relevant information on the ad. At this point I do not know, and it's plenty of IT jobs in search engines out there.