# What's the intended flow for people to answer to a job offer message?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I didn't really know how to phrase this in one title, so here is my problem: I am quite confuse on what to do when I get a message from someone who offers a job.

#### On the SO website, in my messages

I get two buttons "Interested", "Not interested".
But, I wonder what they do:

- "Do they send a response right away?"
- "Can I still write something after or will it force some kind of steps?" They look a bit like an ultimatum.

#### On the other hand, I also get an email.

The email address is `<do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com>`, so I think well I can not respond, right?

But then, there is a small line at the top saying `"Reply above this line or view on Stack Overflow"`.  So, I can respond, actually?

Moreover, apart from this link that is "view on Stack Overflow" there are also the "I'm interested" / "I'm not interested" links at the bottom of the email.

But, if I reply to the email, it seems I can "bypass" the `I'm interested/not interested` step.

So what I am really asking is, could we make this process clearer?

- It should be clear if the "I'm interested/not interested" buttons/links still allow for free interaction between the two parties or it they are meant to be a quick "yes/no". Especially for the "no", is this a "no and don't bother me anymore"?
- If we can reply to an email, it should not come from a "do-not-reply" address. EDIT: I read the reasons why it is like this. If this can not change, adding a meaningful note in the email could help.
- If we can somehow "bypass" the interested/not interested links, then are they necessary? What's better for me and the person who contacted me? I answer manually or I click the buttons?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350303/please-reply-to-do-not-replystackoverflow-com, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298112/clarify-what-the-yes-no-responses-do-in-careers-reply-interface, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370817/improve-not-interested-message-to-employers

Comment: Can I just say: that was some really beautifully worded feedback. :)

Comment: I sometimes like to write a reply anyway even as I decline an offer. I usually write the message ahead in a text editor because it feels awkward to decline and only then start writing a reply which is then posted X minutes after the decline message…

Comment: For the "do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com" email address, that's the "from" address of the notification email. There's a different "reply-to" address which is unique to the message, and virtually all mordern email clients will use that one when the user hits "reply". I believe that's a pretty standard pattern. Although I would agree that do-not-reply@ is confusing in that case, we should change that to something hit-reply@.